# App targets .NET 4, Setup insists on installing .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio-2013, vsto

I've written an Excel plugin in C#.
It is targeted for .NET 4.

When I publish and create a setup, the installation tries to install .NET 4.5.

How can I stop the installer from installing .Net 4.5?

Thanks for any help!

The setup files are as follows:

```
Addin.vsto
setup.exe
[Application Files]
  [Addin]
    [de]
    [es]
    [fr]
    ...
    [zh-Hans]
      Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy
      Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.resources.dll.deploy
    [zh-Hant]
      Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll.deploy
      Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.resources.dll.deploy
    Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll.deploy
    Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll.deploy
    Addin.dll.deploy
    Addin.dll.manifest
    Addin.vsto
    sapnco.dll.deploy
    sapnco_utils.dll.deploy
```

the Addin.vsto file contains this snippet:

```
  <compatibleFrameworks xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
    <framework targetVersion="4.0" profile="Full" supportedRuntime="4.0.30319" />
  </compatibleFrameworks>
```

MS Office is installed on the client.

(Question reposted after being incorrectly closed as a duplicate)

Comment: Have a look at all the referenced libraries, I am suspecting one of them to be a 4.5 only DLL

Comment: I didn't think that was possible but you could be right. I'll investigate, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the list of prerequsites (choose another .net framework version: .net 4.5 -> .net 4.0) of the add-in installer instead (not the Addin.vsto file).

The following articles describes the required steps for creating an installer for Office add-ins in depth:

- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx)
- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx)

Comment: Spot on! I have never needed to change those before. thanks :)